# Django Admin CSS files unaccessible without deprecated ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX

Tags: django, apache, django-admin, mod-wsgi, django-1.4

I'm a first time django user. I had to manually add in the following deprecated function to the new django1.4 settings.py file for my admin css to be accessible. How can make my site look pretty without using this deprecated function?

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

Here are my other settings for your perusal:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/static/' 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And my apache http.conf file has:

```
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/static/
<Directory /home/ubuntu/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: have you run `collectstatic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must run

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

to copy all static files from packages to static directory. Of course django.contrib.staticfiles must be in INSTALLED_APPS.

There will be folder "admin" in static folder after that. If it exists and still static files not loaded, then look to your webserver config.